# C reading values into double array, read values are different from values on local file

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I've attempted to read a column of values in `txt` file into a double array in C (I haven't written C/C++ for years, take me as a newbie). The values in file and the values in the double array were different. I don't understand why and how to correct it.

I've locked C standard to C99 in CMAKE as well because other parts of my C codebase come from very old time (2006). But they are only after these values are correctly read.

Here's the code snippet to do so:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
    int main(){
        double *input = malloc(sizeof(double) * 30);
        FILE *fReader= fopen("../values.txt", "r");
        if (fReader == NULL){
            perror("following error occurred:");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        // If I use input[i] instead, it's causing a segfault.
            if(fscanf(fReader, "%f", (input+i)) != 1){
                perror("following error occurred during value reading: ");
                fclose(fReader);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            printf( "%current value is %e \n", *(input+i));
        }
    
        if (ferror(fReader)){
            perror("following error occurred after reading: ");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (fclose(fReader)){
            perror("following error occurred closing file: ");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

This code ran ok, what's interesting was the values read in were different from the values on file.

Here's the output from `gdb` by doing `p *input@30@1`:

```
$1 = {
  {
    5.2090851696161347e-315,
    1.5708573496820653e-314,
    5.1267133989091838e-315,
    0,
    1.5717337030679671e-314,
    5.1214795787184985e-315,
    1.5632763856615201e-314,
    1.5698868046570466e-314,
    5.1603745953073066e-315,
    1.5776507290912971e-314,
    5.1890476209538565e-315,
    1.5757154067636091e-314,
    5.1701259393153366e-315,
    1.5646987621187767e-314,
    1.5706057487281833e-314,
    1.5745646547527293e-314,
    5.074800315787295e-315,
    1.5708606090331309e-314,
    1.5584251847289437e-314,
    5.0712624352138373e-315,
    1.5742053425473973e-314,
    5.121533268832232e-315,
    1.5713904213165801e-314,
    1.5767611663662882e-314,
    5.1426528410215284e-315,
    1.5729652822422439e-314,
    5.1593853918931727e-315,
    1.5747322610883588e-314,
    4.9742190195450526e-315,
    5.0023562211173747e-315
  }
}
```

And here's the file content (called `values.txt`):

```
0.421499729344799
-0.0637534886782198
0.106157122495887
0
-0.0769690171367188
0.0982644454758486
-0.0186078658644284
-0.0558087634241033
0.188837376753259
-0.207397239912854
0.300632085420638
-0.149027358129317
0.218247717844644
-0.0239702769714967
-0.0612296530370315
-0.119660179409031
0.0451857273951361
-0.0638026393400715
-0.00797183286147529
0.0425181372831318
-0.114241700013729
0.0983454129367622
-0.0717922840839158
-0.18056777523574
0.135388066712405
-0.0955414085415107
0.185853919257983
-0.122187706120336
0.00796167779508749
0.0132655904045542
```

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: Thanks! this is actually crucial, one of those things I wanted to know but don't know what to ask in C. On a side note, I should be able to set them in CMAKE as compiler options right? @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%f"` in `scanf()` is for reading `float`. Use `"%lf"` (add `l`) instead for reading `double`.

You can use `&input[i]` (not `input[i]` without `&`) instead of `(input+i)` to read values.

Also note that the line

```c
printf( "%current value is %e \n", *(input+i));
```

invokes *undefined behavior* by

- passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%c` requests `int`, but `*(input+i)` has type `double`.
- not providing data corresponding to `%e`.

Comment: The error in the `printf` call is not that they are passing a `double` for `%c` but that they did not intend to have a format conversion there at all; `%c` should be just `c`.

Comment: sharp eyes! this is good to know as well; however that `%` wasn't intentional though, it was my typo but yeah I'll remember it.

Comment: Ah I think it comes to me now: `input` is a pointer to the first elemenet of array and to access the value of it we use `input[0]`, and to get the address of that value we should be using `&input[0]` and most importantly, fscanf takes a pointer to address, not a value itself.

Comment: I do have one more question if you don't mind: if I don't  initialize my `double *input` and leave it as `double *input;` I got segmentation fault. I don't think in C99 that we have to initialize pointer right? but why is the segmentation fault ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @stucash Pointers are not required to be initialized if it is not used. A valid region of memory is required for storing values, so it must be initialized before using to determine where to store values. It is not necessary to be initialized at declaration. Assigning valid pointer later is also OK if it is done before using.

Comment: right, so it doesn't matter when but it has to be initialized before it's used if my intention for that pointer is to use it to store values and use it later.

Answer (score 1):

OP's key mistake is **not** about using a "mis-match specifier and type", although that is an error among others.

The **major mistake**: not using a good compiler was all warnings enabled.

```
warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 3 has type 'double *' [-Wformat=]
if (fscanf(fReader, "%f", (input + i)) != 1) {

warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
printf("%current value is %e \n", *(input + i));

warning: format '%e' expects a matching 'double' argument [-Wformat=]
printf("%current value is %e \n", *(input + i));
```

Save yourself (and others) time: **Enable all compiler warnings**  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630728/c-reading-values-into-double-array-read-values-are-different-from-values-on-loc/75632069#comment133428898_75630728)

Well enabled good compilers have the sharpest eyes.

Comment: I actually do agree with you, as well as Eric; the major unknown unknown here, is that I don't know what to ask to get these warnings manifested as errors in the first place and I don't know these could be manifested as wwarning (and in turn elevated to error), it'd really save a lot of time banging my head and writing a reprex on SO.

Comment: @stucash Employing  [Eric's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75630728/c-reading-values-into-double-array-read-values-are-different-from-values-on-loc/75632069?noredirect=1#comment133428898_75630728), have you successfully received similar warnings now?

Comment: yep I used target_compile_options in CMAKE to add `-Wall -Werror` that's my current setting for the compiler. I'd really hope there's a good article discussing a good environment setup, starting from compiler, then probably linker problems and some common code practice (maybe Scott Meyer's Effective C++ would do a good job here) for C/C++.  I wasn't able to find one though.

Comment: @stucash You may find even more useful warnings with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` useful.

Comment: gotcha that'll be my new setting going forward :) and thank you very much for the help!